# Is it possible to define object parameters in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I'm new to testing and am wondering if it is possible to define object parameters with PHPUnit. I attempted to define attributes on a mock and it ignored it.

```
$testMock = $this->getMock('ClassToMock');
$testMock->attribute = "something";
```

Is it just better practice to access attributes via methods? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot inject property value via mock api. you can do that via reflection mechanism.

```
$testMock = $this->getMock('ClassToMock');
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($testMock);
$reflection_property = $reflection->getProperty('attribute');
$reflection_property->setValue($testMock, 'something');
```

if you need that "hacks" probably you should refactor your code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Kind of figured it was code smell but thought it better to ask.